# Excel PowerPivot from two different files

Tags: excel, powerpivot

How can I create a PivotTable from two different excel files. They have the same column names and data types. I tried from the Get & Transform data menu, but without success. Exactly which options
should I use, step-by-step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one Query for each Excel file (Connection Only), then combine those two queries into one new Query which you load into the Data Model...

Screenshot from Power Query Editor, Home tab:

[image]